Deploying code from GitHub to server on main branch push
I have a Bluehost server for my website and I would like to setup a GitHub action to automatically ssh into my server and pull the code from the main branch.
Currently I do this manually using these steps:

$ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
type password
cd to the location
git pull origin main
type github username
type github PAT

I have tried to learn how to automate these with tools like GitHub actions however I have not been able to get it to work. I would like things like passwords to be kept a secret (although the repo is private) and I believe I can do that with github secrets and variables.
So I think I have all of the tools to do what I need, I just cannot seem to put the script together to actually get it done.
Also to clarify I want it to deploy the code when I make a change to the main branch only.

Your manual steps seem fine from the Git point of view. For automating steps 1 and 2, take a look at some options in this question. For automating steps 4,5, and 6, take a look at this question. The combination of those two may be your answer.
